# Continuous function from connected metric space to disrcete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, connectedness

In the following (Terence 2006, p.38) I have to prove as exercice:

*Let $f : X \to Y$ be a function from a connected metric space $(X, d)$ to a metric space $(Y, d_{disc} )$ with the discrete metric. Show that $f$ is continuous if and only if it is constant*

I have proven this proposition without using the fact that $X$ is connected, so obviously I did something wrong. I would be very gratefull if you could point out my mistake.

*Proof:* $\impliedby$ Suppose  $f$ is constant, i.e.,
$$\forall x,x'\in X: f(x) = f(x')$$
Choose an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$. Then, no matter what our choice of $\delta_{\varepsilon}$ is, due to the definition of the discrete metric we always have
$$ d(x,x_0)<\delta_{\varepsilon} \implies d_{disc}(f(x),f(x_0))=0<\varepsilon$$

$\implies$ Now suppose that $f$ is continuous. Then, for any $x_0 \in x$ we have
$$\forall \varepsilon>0 \quad \exists \delta_{\varepsilon}>0 \quad \forall x \in X: \quad d(x,x_0)<\delta_{\varepsilon} \implies d_{disc}(f(x),f(x_0))<\varepsilon$$
Now suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $f$ is not constant, i.e.,
$$\exists x_0 \in X \quad \forall x \in X/\{x_0\}: f(x) \neq f(x_0)$$
But then, for such $x_0$ we cannot find a $\delta_{0.5}$ so that $d(x,x_0)<\delta_{\varepsilon} \implies d_{disc}(f(x),f(x_0))<0.5$ - a contradiction.

Comment: Your direction is reversed. In your attempt, $\impliedby$ first, $\implies$ second.

Comment: Corrected it, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: "$f$ is not constant" does not mean that $f(x) \neq f(x_0)$ for all $x\neq x_0$.

Comment: Also your proof did not use the assumption that $X$ is connected.

Comment: Hint: is there any relationship between connectedness and continuous functions?

Comment: Yes, the fact that I did not use the assumption that $X$ is connected made me suspicious. Do you mean that I have to use the theorem that states that continuity preserves connectedness and then contradict it with the fact that every image consisting of more than one value in the discrete space is disconnected?

Comment: Yes, if you have learned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y_1,y_2 \in f(X)$. Write $Y=Y_1 \cup Y_2$ where $Y_1 \cap Y_2 = \emptyset$ and $y_1 \in Y_1,y_2 \in Y_2$. Since $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are open sets as its a discrete metric space, $f^{-1}(Y_i)$ must be open and $X=f^{-1}(Y_1) \cup f^{-1}(Y_2)$ contradicting the connectedness of the metric space $X$.